# New fields saved in Wordpress User profile

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created an extra field in the profile of all users that are created when sending a purchase with Wocommerce:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="DNI"></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'dni', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br/>
                <span class="description">DNI</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

To save it:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

    function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
            return false; 
        }
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dni', $_POST['dni'] );
    }
```

I've also created an extra field in the Wocommerce purchase form using the plugin "Checkout Field Editor".

Now I'd like to link those fields and that when making a purchase the value entered is saved in that one created in the profile.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question and share the code that you have already used for this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @L7c1f3r Question edited, sorry

Comment: The following code line ensures that the field (profile) changes are saved in the database 'update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dni', $_POST['dni'] );' 
and this code line shows the value from the database in the field (profile) 'get_the_author_meta( 'dni', $user->ID )'. So 
it comes down to it if you save the field (Checkout Field Editor) the user meta in the database should be overwritten, or the opposite (value=... get from database where checkoutfield is saved). You will therefore have to look at how that plugin stores the data (read the documentation) and adjust it to your field (profile).